# Scanner error with nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use Scanner to get an int from the keyboard, but I getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at TableReader.mainMenu(TableReader.java:122)
    at TableReader.main(TableReader.java:76)
```

This is what I have. It is independent of the rest of my program, I don't understand why this isn't working. It is declared in a method that is being called in a while loop, if that helps.

```
    // scan for selection
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = s.nextInt();           // error occurs at this line
    s.close();
```

I stepped through with the debugger and narrowed the error down to:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6bdc8a8, pid=5587, tid=1828186944

JRE version: 7.0_07-b30
 Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x4258a8]  java_lang_String::utf8_length(oopDesc*)+0x58

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use the `hasNextXXXX()` methods from the `Scanner` class to make sure that there is an integer ready to be read.

The problem is you are called `nextInt()` which reads the next integer from the stream that the `Scanner` object points to, if there is no integer there to read (i.e. if the input is exhausted then you will see that `NoSuchElementException`)

From the JavaDocs, the `nextInt()` method will throw these exceptions under these conditions:

- InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer
                          regular expression, or is out of range
- NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
- IllegalStateException  - if this scanner is closed

You can fix this easily using the `hasNextInt()` method:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = 0;

if(s.hasNextInt()) 
{
   choice = s.nextInt();
}

s.close();
```

Comment: This sends me into an infinite loop because what is within the brackets never gets called

Comment: @spatara Yes it checks to see if whatever the next item that the Scanner is pointing to can successfully be converted to an integer, if it can then `hasNextInt()` will return true, otherwise it will return false.

Comment: I am just reading from the keyboard, there is no nextInt when the method is called

Comment: I am still stuck...hasNextInt() is returning false because it checks before I type the int...

Comment: @spatara It tries to interpret whatever you print as an integer

Comment: but it does not interpret anything...it sees nothing, Do I understand this correctly? If I havent typed anything, hasNextInt() will return false, no?

Comment: `hasNextInt()` will wait for your input. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, and I get an infinite loop...maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: @spatara.. See  my post to get how not to get into an infinite loop..