# Scanner NoSuchElement Exception Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, output

Can someone tell me why this code is throwing the NoSuchElementException?
I've used scanner before for input and output but haven't ever had a problem with it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TaskRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the month: ");
        int month = (keyboard.nextInt() - 1);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the day: ");
        int day = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print(day);
    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown at line 10 since everyone's asking.
Also heres the stack trace.

```
Enter the year: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at TaskRunner.main(TaskRunner.java:10)
```

Comment: I am able to execute this program perfectly without any exceptions. At what line it is throwing error?

Comment: At which line did you have exception?

Comment: Every time when you try to explain exception add stack trace. Without stack trace very hard to help you.

Comment: Please post the exception trace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832006/java-scanner-error-with-nextint

Comment: You don't have a habit of randomly typing ctrl+d, do you? In any case, I'd suggest you attempt Thai Tran's suggestion

Comment: Lol.. Couldn't find the error. Works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: works perfectly fine on eclipse.