# Java - Errormessage unknown reason

Tags: java, error-handling, while-loop

I am pretty new to Java, but know some of C and Python, hence some of Java looks alike. I have a program that worked well, until I tried to create a "main menu". I did as I've always done in the previous languages, but the program will only work ONE time through the loop, then crash.

Code in which error occurs:

```
while (true)
        {   
            java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Alternative 1. Add A New Person To Database");
            System.out.println("Alternative 2. Quit The Program");

            int choice = in.nextInt(); //This is where error is found! (:22)

            if (choice==1)
            {
                choice1();
            }
            if (choice==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Look at the file text.txt");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at EgnaProgrammet.main(EgnaProgrammet.java:22)
```

I'm certain that something is wrong with the input since the problem occurs the second time I want to make a input in the while. Could it be because `choice` already has a value?

Appriciate any help!

Comment: My input is either 1 or 2. ONLY those. Observe that it works fine the first "loop". Problem occurs the second time.

Comment: You should use the hasNextXXXX() methods from the Scanner class to make sure that there is an integer ready to be read. 

Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832006/scanner-error-with-nextint

Comment: In addition you should only use one instance of a scanner instead of creating a new one at each iteration.

Comment: @KevinEsche Your comment is the root cause of the problem.  But yes, he should also maybe have some logic to handle a non integer input.

Comment: will check the links and try to solve it. as for input handling, I will do it when this problem is solved. One step at a time! :)

Comment: @BhushanPatil if I do that, then the answer "choice", will be inside the if-statement and therefore will not be seen by the rest of the method.

Comment: What output do you get from `System.in.available()`?

Comment: 0. not sure what that does anyway

Comment: It will tell you whether the `System.in` stream is available?  If this is returning false, then you likely have found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input) (and likely a few others).  What is happening is that in the first iteration of the `while` loop you are instantiating a `Scanner` object using the `System.in` input stream.  In each subsequent iteration of the loop, you are creating a new `Scanner` object, which then closes the `System.in` input stream.

Change your code to this:

```
// declare your Scanner only once, *outside* the while loop
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(System.in.available());

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Alternative 1. Add A New Person To Database");
    System.out.println("Alternative 2. Quit The Program");

    int choice = in.nextInt(); //This is where error is found! (:22)

    if (choice == 1) {
        choice1();

    } else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Look at the file text.txt");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this previously, but when encountering the problem, decided to put it inside and also added "in.close();" at the bottom. But I realised that it wasn't the problem, so probably should've brought it outside again.

Comment: I think it is the problem.  What error message do you get when running my code?

Comment: It makes no difference to put it outside (except I dont waste resources calling it every time), hence I get the same error. Problem seems to be as described by the others. will try to do that now

Comment: Try adding this line of code immediately after you create the `Scanner`: `System.out.println(System.in.available());`

Answer (score 0):

You must have next line for scanner. I think this post will help you

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

also scanner has a method "hasNext()" you can use it like:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
// do sth
}
```