# How to take multiple inputs via scanner from the user in the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I want to initialize the constructor which is in another class with the multiple inputs taken in for loop in the main method of another class. but the output is coming only one input. kindly solve my problem.

s1.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class s1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name="";int roll=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            name=sc.nextLine();
            roll=sc.nextInt();

            s2 sample=new s2(name,roll);

            sample.display();

        } 
    }
}
```

s2.java

```
public class s2 {
    String name="";int roll=0;
    s2(String name,int roll) {
        this.name=name;
        this.roll=roll;
    }
    void display() {
        System.out.println(name+" "+roll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: use meaning full names please. First of all, java class names go UpperCamelCase ... and then s2 is a poor name. Why not "ExampleUser" or something alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more then 1 time change the condition `i<2` which restrict loop for one iteration.

Change to `i<10` for example for getting uoto 9 times (10-1) inputs/outputs

Add condition

```
 if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
      roll=sc.nextInt();
      s2 sample=new s2(name,roll);
      sample.display();
  }
```

Comment: If the loop condition is increased then after displaying one input and after entering second input "InputMismatchException" error is displaying in the compiler.

Comment: Add condition before it `if(sc.hasNextInt()) {` updated answer

Comment: Can you explain me the reason for using this condition and if we can use this condition then we can also use the same for String input?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832006/scanner-error-with-nextint